# How to omit a single word from a file processed by getword

Tags: c, cpu-word

My task is to write a program which is supposed to omit a single word after a specific sequence in the previous ones.
I've already prepared a working getword procedure (returns `char *`), now I only have problems with main where I have the following snippet of code, which allows me to detect where should I remove the word. But I don't know how to actually omit/remove that word from the outfile.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *infile = NULL, *outfile = NULL;
    char *word = NULL;
    int c;
    int yes = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    /* completely irrelevant - opening, writing to files, error messages etc. */
    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(infile);

        word = getword(infile);
        if (counter == 2) {
            counter = 0;
            yes = 0;
                    /* here it should somehow omit the word */
            continue;
        }
        if (choose(word, strlen(word))) {
            fputs(word, outfile);
            counter++;
            yes = 1;
        } else {
            fputs(word, outfile);
            if (yes == 1) {
                counter--;
            }   
        }
        free(word); 
    }
    /* completely irrelevant */
}
```

**EDIT:** Added to clarify

"getword just reads a word, it doesn't perform any check whether it is the word I'm looking for. main() does that check. When the if (choose) is satisfied then it means that word contains sequence of letters I'm looking for, and the second word after that particular word should be omitted. Variables "counter" and "yes" may not be the perfect algorithm, but at first I want it to work, then I'll try to simplify that. "Counter" counts up to 2 to determine which word is to be omitted, and "yes" helps to increment the counter after we move to a word not satisfying `if (choose)` condition."

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, in the place of

`/* here it should somehow omit the word */`

there should be `free(word);`

Everything works like charm. 
I got it earlier, but forgot to post answer to my own question :D

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove that word from the outfile. You need omit it from input file.

```
word = getword(infile);
```

I suppose here you get the word which you need to omit. Isn't it? 
You can get length of this word and do the next cycle

```
int len = strlen(word); 
for (int i=0; i<=len; i++) 
   fgetc(infile); //we also omit the special char
```

From this moment you can do **continue**.

**Edit:** I think that checking

```
if(!isalpha(c))
```

is not good because space is not an alphabetic letter. 
May be this variant is better

```
if (c!='\\')
```

In this case the char **'\'** is a special char.

Comment: Checks are all good, and satisfy my task. I'm asking only how to actually omit a word. You idead with for loop is not bad, however, not good neither. I can't omit it in the input file, because my test `choose` must a get `*word` as an argument. So word needs to be read from the infile.

Comment: I answered your question. 
See line with the comment //we also omit special char.

Comment: You actually read this word from input file. You just don't remember it and don't put in output file.

Comment: I don't see sense in variables "counter" and "yes". May be I didn't get the task

Comment: getword just reads a word, it doesn't perform any check whether it is the word I'm looking for. main() does that check. When the if (choose) is satisfied then it means that word contains sequence of letters I'm looking for, and the second word after that particular word should be omitted. Variables "counter" and "yes" may not be the perfect algorithm, but at first I want it to work, then I'll try to simplify that. "Counter" counts up to 2 to determine which word is to be omitted, and "yes" helps to increment the counter after we move to a word not satisfying `if (choose)` condition.